# Is Stinky the Snail fast enough to collect all dropped coins in the zen garden?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I have a full Zen garden that needs watering. If I water every plant as fast as I can, will Stinky the Snail be able to collect all the coins for me without any disappearing (with or without chocolate)?

Secondary question that would answer the first I guess. Do coins disappear in the Zen Garden at all?

Comment: If you exit the garden he will be collecting the coins instantly during the time he is awake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coins in the Zen Garden are no different from coins in the game itself. They will disappear after a set amount of time.

As for Stinky the Snail, I personally have not tested if he can collect all the coins without chocolate. I know for a fact that if you give him and all the plants chocolate and then go grab a coffee, he will be able to collect most of them.

Comment: I can give plants chocolate?

Comment: Yes. Makes them wiggle faster and make coins faster.

Comment: Stinky the Snail with chocolate is not fast enough to collect all of the coins. Especially if you use chocolate on your flowers. However, he will collect **most** of them, so it is still very beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Stinky the Snail will collect most of the coins in the zen garden for three minutes. If you feed him a piece of chocolate he will stay awake for an hour. Feeding plants chocolate will decrease the percentage of coins earned by Stinky. So in short coins do disappear.

[Source.](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Stinky_the_Snail)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Although Stinky the Snail will move faster during that time, he is not fast enough to collect **all** of the coins under all circumstances before they disappear.